# Bootstrap v3 form does not work in 768 size mobile when using col-sm-#

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I created a form in Bootstrap v3. Here's a sample code;

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-3">
        <label>Hotel Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

In large or default sized screen, its size is that of `col-md-4`, but since in 768 screen if you would not assign a size it will automatically adjust to full width size as that of `col-md-12`. Now, I wanted to assign a width for my form that's why I add `col-sm-3` to my class. The output of it in a 768 screen is that of width `col-sm-3` but the problem is I can't seem to input a text in the input text attribute. It seems like it has been disabled or something. What could be the problem to this?

Your help is much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be careful how you use the col-# classes. The following code will fix your issue.

```
<form role="form">

     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-3">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Hotel Name</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
             </div>
         </div> 
     </div>

</form>
```

If you have the row on the outer side of the form, you won't need to include this inside the form either.